# After scrcpy installation and then android studio, nothing is removing or uninstalling

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, android, android-studio

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,616 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of android-studio:
 android-studio depends on android-studio-2020.3.1; however:
  Package android-studio-2020.3.1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package android-studio (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
               Errors were encountered while processing: android-studio
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to add the [related PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emaarten-fonville/+archive/ubuntu/android-studio) again and then reinstall Android Studio by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall android-studio-2020.3.1
sudo apt-get install --reinstall android-studio
```